# good way to read text file in C

Tags: c

I need to read a text file which may contain long lines of text. I am thinking of the best way to do this. Considering efficiency, even though I am doing this in C++, I would still choose C library functions to do the IO.

Because I don't know how long a line is, potentially really really long, I don't want to allocate a large array and then use `fgets` to read a line. On the other hand, I do need to know where each line ends. One use case of such is to count the words/chars in each line. I could allocate a small array and use `fgets` to read, and then determine whether there is `\r,` `\n`, or `\r\n` appearing in the line to tell whether a full line has been read. But this involves a lot of `strstr` calls (for `\r\n`, or there are better ways? for example from the return value of fgets?). I could also do `fgetc` to read each individual char one at a time. But does this function have buffering?

Please suggest compare these or other different ways of doing this task.

Comment: Use C++ and `std::string` and `std::getline`. Why not? Profile before you claim it's too slow.

Comment: Note that `fgets()` will not read `\r` as an end of line under normal circumstances.  Look at POSIX 2008 and [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) but beware of the portability implications of using it.  (OTOH, it is not dreadfully hard to provide your own implementation if need so be.)  All possible line endings is trickier - even POSIX `getline()` only deals with a single delimiter character (as does `getdelim()` on the same page).

Comment: Read in the whole file with fread() or read(), then go searching for the '\n's. Something similar can be done using mmap().

Comment: `fgetc()` does have buffering, as do `getc()` and `getchar()`.  Most of the input is described in terms of 'as if by calling `getc()'.

Comment: "Considering efficiency, even though I am doing this in C++, I would still choose C library functions to do the IO": Where did you find the bottleneck to be when you profiled your C++ code?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do I/O depends on what you're going to do with the data.  If you're counting words, line-based input doesn't make much sense.  A more natural approach is to use fgetc and deal with a character at a time and let stdio worry about the buffering.  Only if you need the whole line in memory at the same time to process it should you actually allocate a buffer big enough to contain it all.